# How to protect user if can't return nullptr for an empty stack?

Tags: c++, stack, nullptr

I am trying to code the implementation of the Cube, Stack example given in this [Coursera course example of Towers of Hanoi](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/cs-fundamentals-1/4-2-tower-of-hanoi-introduction-aLUTd) to learn more C++.

In `stack.h` I have to implement:

```
class Stack {
public:
void push_back(const Cube & cube);
Cube removeTop();
Cube & peekTop();
unsigned size() const;

friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const Stack & stack);

private:
std::vector<Cube> cubes_;
};
```

The issue I have is with `removeTop()`. I was thinking of returning `nullptr` if the stack (vector) is empty because `pop_back`'s behavior is undefined for an empty vector.

> Calling pop_back on an empty container is undefined. [Cpp Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/pop_back)

```
inline Cube Stack::removeTop() {
  if (!cubes_.empty()) {
    Cube top_cube = cubes_.back();
    cubes_.pop_back();
    return top_cube;
  }
  else {
    return nullptr;
  }
}
```

However, I get an error during compilation.

```
./stack.h:35:12: error: no viable conversion from returned value of type
      'std::__1::nullptr_t' to function return type 'uiuc::Cube'
    return nullptr;
```

How can I protect the user if I can't return a `nullptr`? Am I limited to just telling the user that the function should not be called on an empty stack and let him/her take care of the checking?

Comment: That's one option. Another option will be to use, well, `std::optional` as the return value. If you are not familiar with how to use `std::optional`, you should find more documentation in your C++ book.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, thanks. It is not a book but a video course. I will look into `std::optional`. Haven't gotten to it yet. I was coding on my own before looking at the suggestion.

Comment: A function that returns a `Cube` can only return `nullptr` if `Cube` is a pointer, or has a constructor that accepts a pointer.   Your options include (1) passing a reference to `Cube` and returning an `int` or `bool` that is used to indicate if it was possible to pop from the stack  (2) returning `std::optional`  (3) throwing an exception if the stack is empty.   Options (1) and (2) require the caller to check.  Option (3) forces the caller (or a caller of the caller) to catch an exception (otherwise the program will terminate).

Comment: @Peter: Why don't you post you comment as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly what exceptions are for:

```
if (cubes_.empty())
    throw std::runtime_error("stack underflow");
Cube top_cube = cubes_.back();
cubes_.pop_back();
return top_cube;
```

Complicating this with `std::optional` is almost certainly **not** the right answer here. Attempting to pop from an empty stack means the program has lost its way. That should be a hard error, not something that's masked by an interface that says "you might or might not have this, please check afterwards".

Comment: Absolutely right. Calling pop on an empty stack is definitely a hard error.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this:

```
inline bool Stack::removeTop(Cube& top_cube) {
  if (!cubes_.empty()) {
    top_cube = cubes_.back();
    cubes_.pop_back();
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: There are many reasons for this approach to be undesirable: it always constructs an object, and then copy-assigns it. So this will not be a desirable approach when copy-assignment and/or construction is an expensive operation. It won't work at all if the object has a deleted copy assignment operator.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the function signature, you have to implement, you really can't.  Typically, you'd guard this sort of thing with an assertion.  In some situations you might use the [NullObject pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern), or you could return a junk object.  In newer C++ versions, you can also use `std::optional<T>`.

```
inline Cube Stack::removeTop() {
  if (!cubes_.empty()) {
    Cube top_cube = cubes_.back();
    cubes_.pop_back();
    return top_cube;
  }
  else {
    return Cube {};
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [pyj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1265214/pyj) noted, since c++17 there is a new mechanism to do so (adopting boost::optional idea). This is the *std::optional* container. When using *std::optional*, you tell the user of this function, that he might get an **empty response**, and therefore, he must check whether it is initialized or not.

From the cpp reference:

> The class template std::optional manages an optional contained value, i.e. a value that may or may not be present.
>
> A common use case for optional is the return value of a function that may fail. As opposed to other approaches, such as std::pair, optional handles expensive-to-construct objects well and is more readable, as the intent is expressed explicitly.

Now for the usage:

```
inline std::optional<Cube> Stack::removeTop() 
{
    if (!cubes_.empty()) 
    {
        Cube top_cube = cubes_.back();
        cubes_.pop_back();
        return top_cube;
    }
    else 
    {
        return std::nullopt;
    }
}
```

And, while you get a std::optional, and not a Cube, there is no **memory allocation** on the heap, which is a great advantage over using pointers for the same output.

> If an optional contains a value, the value is guaranteed to be allocated as part of the optional object footprint, i.e. no dynamic memory allocation ever takes place. Thus, an optional object models an object, not a pointer, even though operator*() and operator->() are defined.

Comment: why not just return `tob_cube` but use the braces?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, they are not necessary (removed them from the example). However, you should notice that the return type **isn't** a Cube - it is std::optional<Cube>, which has operator*, which returns a Cube.

Comment: And what is the result of `operator*` for an empty optional?

Comment: Btw, I am still trying to figure out how to use `std::optional` on a mac. I have seen on stackoverflow that it doesn't work well and I can't update my `Xcode` now.

Comment: The result is undefined according to cpp reference ("The behavior is undefined if *this does not contain a value.") . **However**, this is an idiom - if you use std::optional, you **must** check if it is initialized. It is exactly like using a pointer without checking if it isn't nullptr.

Comment: The macOS error that I can see is with the experimental build of this feature, I would try to use #include <optional> (and not experimental/optional!) with an updated version of your compiler. They all should support it properly now.

Comment: Thanks. I have an old OS.